# Is there an equivalent to Update-package -reinstall when using nuget.exe?

Tags: nuget

I don't know why. But whenever I pull code from a repo that someone else has worked on their .csproj comes with changes that don't work on my machine. In this case, I have found that:

1. Sometimes running `Update-Package -reinstall` fixed reference problems
2. Sometimes opening the .csproj file and then manually removing errors works

I suspect this is something to do with the reference paths defined in the .csproj file, and that the `Update-package -reinstall` command fixes those references relative to the local machine that the project is being built.

is there a way to replicate the `Update-package -reinstall` command using `nuget.exe`?

Comment: Do you have `Nuget.config` that specify folder for packages installation?

Comment: yes. this location is different on different machines

Comment: 1 - Than it is caused? Why not used single configuration?
2 - Do you consider migrate to `PackageReference`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to run `nuget.exe restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory <packages_directory>` where packages_directory is the directory where you want your packages to be downloaded.
You can read more about the restore operation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-restore).

I would recommend that you standardize the build steps in a shared script in your repository. For instance -

```
wget https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe -OutFile nuget.exe
& nuget.exe restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory packages_directory
& msbuild /t:build project.csproj
```

Comment: Thanks for the help (I apologize for unwarranted snarky comments)

Comment: There is currently a bug that prevents this behavior if not using .NET 4.7.1: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6918

Comment: No worries. Thanks for pointing out the issue. I think this should be fixed soon.

Comment: Hi. I'm finding it extremely difficult to build using nuget cli and msbuild. because if i restore packages successfully, the .csproj file is still likely to contain bad references. in Visual Studio this is easy to fix - `Update-package -reinstall`. But this does not seem to be possible for the nuget CLI. I think MSdocs suggest editing the csproj file manually.... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/nuget-packages-missing. is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you trying to add a reference or just reinstall them? In packages.config you cannot add new reference outside VS. If you want to do that then you need to consider using [.NET code sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/) based projects that are supported via the [dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x).
If you are just trying to download all referenced projects then you should be able to restore them using the commands above.

Can you please provide the exact error?

Comment: not trying to add to packages.config file. several developers have a repo on their different machines at different locations. Everytime one of us pushes to a repo the .csproj file updates. i think (but I'm not entirely sure) that the key changes are the hint paths. when I do 'Update-packages -reinstall', it would seem that the hint paths resolve (I think this just changes the hint paths). But when I do a `nuget restore`, the packages don't resolve. I think it's because the hint paths are not changed in this case, and nothing is found where the hint paths are. But I'll confirm tomorrow

Comment: I'm using NuGet.Config

Comment: yes - `update-packages -reinstall` is updating the hint paths in the `.csproj` file. From what I understand, there is no way around having to do this when using nuget package manager. Since the nuget CLI doesn't provide a means of updating hint paths (as far as I know?) I guess it's just impossible to automate a nuget restore in which different machines have different package paths configured.... This seems extremely limiting. is there the potential for an `update-package -reinstall`-like command to be added to the cli?

Comment: You should be able to run a `nuget.exe update` in the project directory and have it update all the references in the config file and the project file. Read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-update)

Comment: I don't think that's working. so: user `A` runs `Update-package -reinstall` on their PC. This results in `<HintPath>../../../etc</HintPath>`. User `B` pulls repo, runs `nuget update ./packages.config && nuget restore -PackagesDirectory .nuget/Packages/` in the repo folder (nuget.exe is on $PATH). `msbuild` then fails because the package folder isn't searched for dependencies

Comment: the only way around this i have seen is to include a `NuGet.Config` file in every repo to specify the packages directory as relative to the repo. if i use a single nuget.config file in a parent directory, then the packages are installed relative to that config file

Comment: This way, when a user runs `Update-package -reinstall`, hint paths correspond to package directories created on user `B`s machine and all is well

Comment: This `wget` link does not exist anymore.